# Is modifying Laravel base config files a bad idea?

Tags: laravel

Laravel comes with some basic config files available in `config` directory.
which each file is basically an associated array.
now, I want to change the structure of `config/mail.php` from

```
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

to

```
'from' => [
    'noreply' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ]
],
```

so I can have several emails with differnt name.

My question is generic here.
What are(if any) disadvantages of modifying structure of the config files?
Is it possible to be troublesome between LTS upgrades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't modify `email.form` data because Laravel [uses the data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#writing-mailables):

> You may specify a global `from` address in your `config/mail.php` configuration file. This address will be used if no other `from` address is specified within the mailable class

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you suggest adding a new array as addresses and store an associated array there in the config/mail.php file?

Comment: @Mehrdad yes, it's the better way.

Comment: What's your opinion on modifying config files structure in general?

Comment: @Mehrdad what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean for example, adding new keys to the returned array, or for example adding 'version'=>'1.0.0' to app.php

Comment: @Mehrdad sure, adding your own keys is perfectly normal.